# Vue - Add CDN component without webpack

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, cdn

I want to add [this](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuejs-auto-complete@0.9.0/dist/build.js) component to my Vue.js project without using webpack.

I've tried adding this to the `head`:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuejs-auto-complete@0.9.0/dist/build.js"></script>
```

And this to the `body`:

```
<autocomplete :source="[{id:1,name:'abc'},{id:2,name:'def'}]"></autocomplete>
```

But the following error happens:

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: autocomplete - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

What should I do?

[Here](https://github.com/charliekassel/vuejs-autocomplete)'s the link to the component on Github.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to register that component first like below

```
components: {
   Autocomplete: window["vuejs-autocomplete"]
}
```

Example

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    Autocomplete: window["vuejs-autocomplete"]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuejs-auto-complete@0.9.0/dist/build.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <autocomplete :source="[{id:1,name:'abc'},{id:2,name:'def'}]"></autocomplete>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I know the name I have to use inside the window bracket?

Comment: I just looked into the `build.js` and its adding a property "vuejs-autocomplete" to `window` when it is not using module.export

Comment: Hello thanks for this answer, this is very interesting. Nevertheless, it seems that the syntax changed for Vue3 and I could not figure out how to do the same with Vue3.

Answer (score 1):

Have you registered it in `Vue.components();` in your `main.js` ?