# Vue3 - autocomplete component without webpack

Tags: autocomplete, vuejs3, cdn

I am using Vue3 without Webpack and now I need to use a component for auto-complete. I have found [this answer for Vue 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58564210/vue-add-cdn-component-without-webpack) and I tried to apply the same with Vue3 as follow:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  ...
}).component('autocomplete', {
    Autocomplete: window["vuejs-autocomplete"]
})
```

```html
<autocomplete :source="[{id:1,name:'abc'},{id:2,name:'def'}]"></autocomplete>
```

But then I get the following warning in the console:

```
[Vue warn]: Component is missing template or render function. 
  at <Autocomplete source= (2) [{…}, {…}] > 
  at <App>
```

I get the same result if I try to use [V-select](https://vue-select.org/) like this:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  ...
}).component('v-select', {
    vSelect: {
        VueSelect: window["v-select"]
    }
})
```

```html
<v-select :options="options"></v-select>
```

How could we use CDN component in Vue 3 without Webpack? Thanks!